# Disable Safari message when using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, safari, alert

I am currently doing a bit of testing with JavaScript scripts on Safari. I would like to know if there is any way to disable the following message and checkbox Safari keeps showing me: "don't show more alerts from this webpage"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the console.log() instead of alert() to test your code. This way you can use the console to check your code and don't need the popups.